# I have set my Ethernet and Wifi in to promiscious mode using ifconfig but still i get the packets which from and to my computer only

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I am trying to create a application using raw sockets to monitor network traffic but i seem to only getting packets which are being addressed from and to my computer.I can't figure out the problem in it but when i was checking out the config i found that no data passes through my enps20 but only passes through wlp5s0 but in my code i have assumed it to be a ethernet protocol.Is that the problem?If so what protocol should i be checking for wlp5s0?

```
void error(int n,char* msg)
{
    if(n==-1)
    {
        perror(msg);
        exit(0);
    }
}

void eth_hdr(struct ethhdr *eth)
{
    printf("Ethernet Header : \n");
    printf("Source MAC:%.2x.%.2x.%.2x.%.2x.%.2x%.2x\t",eth->h_source[0],eth->h_source[1],eth->h_source[2],eth->h_source[3],eth->h_source[4],eth->h_source[5]);
    printf("Dest. MAC:%.2x.%.2x.%.2x.%.2x.%.2x%.2x\t",eth->h_dest[0],eth->h_dest[1],eth->h_dest[2],eth->h_dest[3],eth->h_dest[4],eth->h_dest[5]);
    printf("Proto:%d\n",eth->h_proto);
}

void ip_hdr(struct iphdr *iph)
{
    char address[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    struct sockaddr_in source,destination;
    printf("IP Header : \n");
    printf("%x\t",iph->version);
    printf("%x\t",iph->protocol);
    source.sin_addr.s_addr=iph->saddr;
    destination.sin_addr.s_addr=iph->daddr;
    inet_ntop(AF_INET,&source.sin_addr,address,INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    printf("Source Addr:%s\t",address);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET,&destination.sin_addr,address,INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    printf("Destination Address:%s\n",address);    
}

void udp_display(struct udphdr *udp)
{
    struct sockaddr_in source,destination;
    printf("UDP Header :\n");
    printf("Source Port:%d\t",ntohs(udp->uh_sport));
    printf("Destination Port:%d\t",ntohs(udp->uh_dport));
    char address[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    source.sin_addr.s_addr=udp->source;
    destination.sin_addr.s_addr=udp->dest;
    inet_ntop(AF_INET,&source.sin_addr,address,INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    printf("Source Addr:%s\t",address);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET,&destination.sin_addr,address,INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    printf("Destination Address:%s\n",address);
}

void tcp_display(struct tcphdr *tcp)
{
    struct sockaddr_in source,destination;
    printf("TCP Header :\n");
    printf("Source Port:%d\t",ntohs(tcp->th_sport));
    printf("Destination Port:%d\t",ntohs(tcp->th_dport));
    char address[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    source.sin_addr.s_addr=tcp->source;
    destination.sin_addr.s_addr=tcp->dest;
    inet_ntop(AF_INET,&source.sin_addr,address,INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    printf("Source Addr:%s\t",address);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET,&destination.sin_addr,address,INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    printf("Destination Address:%s\n",address);
}

int  main()
{
    int sockfd,n,on=1,iphdrlen;
    struct ethhdr *eth;
    struct iphdr *iph;
    struct tcphdr *tcp;
    struct udphdr *udp;
    struct sockaddr addr,addr1;
    struct sockaddr_ll address;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    socklen_t len;
    unsigned char *buffer=(unsigned char*)malloc(65536);
    unsigned char *data=(unsigned char*)malloc(65536);    

    memset(buffer,0,65536);
    memset(&addr,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    memset(&addr1,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr));   
    memset(&address,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
    memset(&ifr,0,sizeof(struct ifreq));

    sockfd=socket(AF_PACKET,SOCK_RAW,htons(ETH_P_ALL));
    error(sockfd,"Error in creating a socket");

    char *opt="wlp5s0";
    setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_BINDTODEVICE,opt,len);
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name,opt,sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));
    n=ioctl(sockfd,SIOGIFINDEX,&ifr);
    error(n,"Trouble in getting the Index information");
    address.sll_family=AF_PACKET;
    address.sll_ifindex=ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    address.sll_protocol=htons(ETH_P_ALL);
    n=bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&address,sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
    error(n,"There has been a problem in binding with that interface");

    while (1)
    {
        n=recvfrom(sockfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0,&addr,&len);
        error(n,"There has been a problem recieving the data");
        eth=(struct ethhdr*)&buffer;
        eth_hdr(eth);
        iph=(struct iphdr*)(buffer+sizeof(struct ethhdr));
        ip_hdr(iph);
        iphdrlen=(iph->ihl)*4;
        if(iph->protocol==6)
        {
            tcp=(struct tcphdr*)(buffer+sizeof(struct ethhdr)+iphdrlen);
            tcp_display(tcp);
            data=(buffer+sizeof(struct ethhdr)+iphdrlen+sizeof(struct udphdr));
        }
        else if(iph->protocol==17)
        {
            udp=(struct udphdr*)(buffer+sizeof(struct ethhdr)+iphdrlen);
            udp_display(udp);
           // data=(buffer+sizeof(struct ethhdr)+iphdrlen+sizeof(struct udphdr));
        } 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't you want to bind your packet socket to a specific interface?

Comment: I am very new to programming sockets i don't know know how to bind to particular interface.Could u please explain or provide a proper link for this.Thank you

Comment: On Ethernet this could also be caused by the uplink. If you're connected to an Ethernet switch the filtering you see should be expected. You may want to verify that this is the case by using packet capture utility, such as tcpdump or tshark, and comparing the output. You can also use the source code of said utilities as a reference.

Comment: @user173379 concerning `bind()`, I provided some code as an answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: @OlegMazurov I have tried with tcpdump it works fine with it

Comment: Are you sure about `eth=(struct ethhdr*)&buffer;`? I would have done `eth=(struct ethhdr*)buffer;`.

Comment: @prog-fh That solved one of the problem in the ethernet header but still have the problem in the ip header.I guess i made some mistake similar to that.

Comment: At the beginning of the answer, I just reported two bugs.

Comment: It started as a question relative to the way you can listen to a specific network interface, but it seems to turn into a debugging session... It is just a matter of patience and attention now.

Comment: @prog-fh sorry for that and thank you for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note: I can see at least two bugs in the program provided in the question.

```
n=(int)recvfrom(sockfd,buffer,65536/*sizeof(buffer)*/,0,&addr,&len);
```

`sizeof(buffer)` is the size of the pointer, not the amount which is allocated.

```
eth=(struct ethhdr*)/*&*/buffer;
```

The `&` makes `eth` consider the variable `buffer` itself as the storage; the actual storage is where the variable points to.

---

As in the question it is mentioned that there is a kind of confusion about the interface that is listened to, I provide here a way to select the interface.

A long time ago I used to open a packet-socket, in promiscuous mode, on a specific network-interface like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netpacket/packet.h>

const char * name="eth0";

//---- Create socket ----
int fd=socket(PF_PACKET,SOCK_RAW,htons(ETH_P_ALL));
if(fd==-1)
  { perror("socket"); return -1; }

//---- Find interface index ----
struct ifreq ifr;
memset(&ifr,0,sizeof(struct ifreq));
strncpy(ifr.ifr_name,name,sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));
if(ioctl(fd,SIOCGIFINDEX,&ifr)==-1)
  { perror("ioctl SIOCGIFINDEX"); close(fd); return -1; }
int index=ifr.ifr_ifindex;

//---- Bind socket to interface ----
struct sockaddr_ll addr;
memset(&addr,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
addr.sll_family=AF_PACKET;
addr.sll_ifindex=index;
addr.sll_protocol=htons(ETH_P_ALL);
if(bind(fd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll))==-1)
  { perror("bind"); close(fd); return -1; }

//---- Determine MTU ----
memset(&ifr,0,sizeof(struct ifreq));
strncpy(ifr.ifr_name,name,sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));
if(ioctl(fd,SIOCGIFMTU,&ifr)==-1)
  { perror("ioctl SIOCGIFMTU"); close(fd); return -1; }
unsigned int mtu=ifr.ifr_mtu;

//---- Switch to promiscuous mode ----
struct packet_mreq mr;
memset(&mr,0,sizeof(struct packet_mreq));
mr.mr_ifindex=index;
mr.mr_type=PACKET_MR_PROMISC;
if(setsockopt(fd,SOL_PACKET,PACKET_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,
              &mr,sizeof(struct packet_mreq))==-1)
  { perror("setsockopt PACKET_MR_PROMISC"); close(fd); return -1; }
```

I'm sorry, it is a bit long, but the comments over each part should be self explanatory.

---

`ioctl()` serves **many** purposes; here is the documentation about Linux network devices:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html

---

When binding the packet-socket to an interface, we have to provide `bind()` with an address structure telling which network interface the socket will be bound to.
This specific structure type is `struct sockaddr_ll` (the same way we use `struct sockaddr_in` for ipv4 sockets) and the relevant field if `sll_ifindex` (an integer index).
This index is given by the operating system when enumerating the network devices; we get to know it thanks to a previous call to `ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX)` which retrieves it based on the interface name (`ifr_name` field of the `struct ifreq`).

Comment: Hey that helps a lot but i seriously can't understand how ioctl works and i have tried learning  from different websites for proper examples but couldn't find one.It will be very helpful if u can share a link of good explanation for ioctl.Thanks

Comment: @user173379 I just added a link to the man page that is relevant for `SIOCGIFINDEX` and `SIOCGIFMTU`.

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped a lot to understand ioctl i will try it out and get back to you but could you just clarify what is s11_ifindex is for and should we setsockopt to bindaddress before we actually bind it?

Comment: Hey i have updated the code and as you have said i have binded with my wireless network(Set to promisciuous mode using ifconfig)  but still facing the same problem, my version and protocol are being displayed as zero and source and destination addr are been displayed as 0.0.0.0 .Please look into the updated code and let me know if i'm missing out something.Thanks.